# так как vs. потому что AND так что vs. поэтому

Tags: выбор-слова, словоупотребление

Given:

- `так как` and `потому что`
- `так что` and `поэтому`

What are the reasons to use one over the other?

I suppose they mean the same thing, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: ...and for even more variety, you can also use the particle ведь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically **так как** and **потому что** mean the same, but they do have differences in usage.
They both are used to connect some fact with its reasons (like words 'because' or 'since'), but **так как** can be placed both in the beginning of the sentence and in the middle of it, while **потому что** is used mostly in the middle of the sentence:

> **Так как** я проспал, я не пришел на первый урок. - The reason here goes before the fact, sounds formal.
> **Потому что** я проспал, я не пришел на первый урок. - Sounds innatural, though can be used in some rare cases.
>
> Я не пришел на первый урок **так как** я проспал. - Sounds formal
> Я не пришел на первый урок **потому что** я проспал. - Most neutral form

**Так как**  is more formal and [according to this source](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/648/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA) emerged in formal language at the end of 18th century and become accepted around 1850-es. It become popular because it can be used both at the beginning of the sentence and in the middle of it. According to Лев Поливанов (died in 1899), writers avoided to use **так как** because it sounds bad: "Союз так как ... весьма редко употребляется образцовыми писателями, как неблагозвучный.".

---

**Так что** and **поэтому** are not completely interchangeable. **Поэтому** connects reasons with facts (in other way than *так как* or *потому что*):

> Я проспал, поэтому я не пришел на первый урок.

The reasons and facts are connected in obvious logical way.

**Так что** is less formal. It can be used to summarize all previous thoughts or intentions or reasons in a single sentence (like "So, ..."):

> Наши программы пользуются большой популярностью, новые заказчики просят о расширении возможностей. Есть много идей и для нового проекта. Так что без работы мы в ближайшее время не останемся.

Here some situation is described and the author uses *так что* to express their estimation for the future. I think it can be translated as *so* or *as you can see*, etc.

Comment: One little thing in addition of Artemix message: "поэтому" means "therefore".

Answer (score 0):

Они обозначают одно и то же, и мы используем разные варианты для того, чтобы не говорить постоянно "потому что".

Comment: does that apply to usage in written and spoken form?

Comment: В основном - да, так и есть. Но, если вы хотите более точной информации о литературном русском языке, советую поискать еще информации, я все-таки русский, поэтому не знаю литературного русского в достаточной мере.

Comment: I would describe **"так как"** as a somewhat more bookish. Can be used in speech but "потому что" is way more popular, while in writing they are comparable. **"так что"** is LESS suitable for formal writing as it focuses more on discussion and summarizing whta is said than on objective relationships between statements and things (i.e. okay-ish but not perfect for mathematical writing).

Answer (score 0):

Each pair - synonymous expressions. You can use any.
I never noticed the prevalence of any of the options in an official letter, speech, or somewhere else

But it seems to me, option with `так` is more often used to describe something negative.